# Why is my texture shaded in the viewport?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem, with UV editing in Blender. When I added this texture to this tower model, the texture is shaded for no good reason, and I copy pasted lights everywhere around it, but it still doesn't work. I have no idea what is going on with this.

PS For any other information, I only know the basics of Blender and it's UV editing, so please write stuff that I will be easy for me to understand.

[image]

Comment: Here is the screencapture: [link]:(https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq2dw7gmx00efbx/agrt.png?dl=0)

Comment: it's hard to say what is the problem but it could be inverted normals. in edit mode select all (A) and Ctrl+N to recalculate your normals. (Shift+Ctrl+N to invert)

Comment: you can load the model to PasteAll.org, and add the link here so someone can have a look at it.  If the texture are small enough, then you can 'Pack' that into the .blend file.